# Directly connect Lego EV3 infrared sensor to raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, i2c, sensor

I am wondering can we connect directly Lego EV3 infrared sensor to Raspberry Pi 3 via I2C? 
I tried to cut cable from one side, and connect wires on SDL, SCL, GND and 3.3V pins on Raspberry Pi (3, 5, 6 and 1 pin, respective), but `i2cdetect -y 1` shows that there is nothing on I2C bus.
When I tried to connect sensor to 5V pin (with 5V ground wire from sensor on GND pin of Raspberry), raspberry failed to boot. :)
Is this means that this sensor can not be directly connected or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you link to the sensor specs?  Why do you think it is I2C?

Comment: All Lego Sensors have an I2C interface @joan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I would have advised you to get [female sensor sockets](https://www.dexterindustries.com/shop/female-sockets-lego-mindstorms-nxt-and-ev3/) to not have to cut your wire, though.

However, go through the typical steps regarding I2C devices on the RasPi, like enabling kernel support if you haven't already.

**Wiring**

[image]

This is a picture of a similiar setup. Ignore the blue wire, you don't have that one.

Be ***VERY CAREFUL*** about the cables inside, they might not be what they look like (colouring)

```
5V         -->     green 
SCL        -->     yellow
SDA        -->     blue
GND        -->     red
```

If that does not work, I suggest adding Pullup-Resistors(to 5V) to both, the SDA and SCL lines, of at least 10k value.

Another thing to mention is that the LEGO devices only support the classic Register-style communication.
A typical read operation looks like this:

> `i2c_start(<address>, <write mode>);
>   i2c_write(<register address to read from>);
>   i2c_restart(<address>, <read mode>);
>   i2c_read(<number of bytes to read>);
>   i2c_stop();`